# MySQL Workbench vs phpMyAdmin

Tags: php, mysql, database, phpmyadmin, mysql-workbench

I've only used phpMyAdmin but then I stumbled upon MySQL Workbench that looks promising.

I wonder if someone has tried it out and could give your thoughts about it compared to phpMyAdmin.

Could it replace phpMyAdmin completely?

Comment: Whats the platform you are working with? Windows, Mac, Linux?

Comment: @ neale. why does platform matter? there is workbench for every platform. phpmyadmin is by default cross platform.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Workbench is very nice if you need to visualize your table relationships, basically that's the only thing I've used it for, but I believe phpmyadmin also supports that now, <strike>through a java applet?</strike>, it's called Designer view.

You can access it by clicking on your database in the left-hand frame, and then clicking on the Designer tab.

Also, keep in mind that there are limitations on the free versions, like it cannot reverse engineer existing databases.

Comment: If you click on your database in the left-side frame, there will be a tab called Designer, which will show the relationships between your tables. Now that I look at it completely in HTML, don't know why I assumed it's Java.

Comment: ok so that just visualize my table relationships. pretty good feature. but i guess you cant draw your tables and then create them? you can do that with workbench?

Comment: Nope, it's not that advanced in this regard.

Answer (score 25):

> Could it replace phpmyadmin
>   completely?

Yes it can. Actually you get much more control in [Workbench](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQL_Workbench), especially on the administration side. Probably the main advantage of [phpMyAdmin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phpmyadmin) is in its web user interface, which in some cases can be more convenient than the Workbench client.

Comment: does workbench miss features that phpmyadmin has?

Comment: No, not really. Apart from the web interface.

Answer (score 6):

I do use MySQL Workbench.  I think it has come a long way since its early versions and it's an effective substitute for phpMyAdmin.

I'd use phpMyAdmin mainly for a webhosting environment, if your client PC is not allowed to connect directly to the MySQL server, but a web app in that server environment is allowed to.

Comment: has workbench completely replaced phpmyadmin when it comes to features? does phpmyadmin has features that you would like to have in workbench?

Comment: Everything I need is supported by Workbench, but YMMV. I don't know if there's a one-for-one matching of features between the two products.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.sqlbuddy.com/ is pretty awesome too. Lighter-weight for just looking at your tables. Great UI too.

Answer (score 1):

[DB Visualizer](http://www.dbvis.com/) is my cross-platform, cross-DB tool of choice - it also has good reverse engineering and visualisation (duh!) support.

Answer (score 1):

I'm beginning to get my hands dirty with MySQL Workbench 5. So far, it's rather comprehensive for a non-web interface client. I'm augmenting our MySQL environment with phpMyAdmin because we do web hosting. I find phpMyAdmin to be intuitive for our customers.